# If the item on XML does not have enclosure

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, rss

Help me please!
I make a simple RSS Reader.

If Rss feed has an image in all items, then the XMLPullParcer is working correctly.

But if the image is not present in all Items, then where there are no them, the parcer takes them from the previous item and inserts it into the empty space.

This also results in a duplicate entry in the SQLite database column.

It is necessary for the parser to display the image, only where it is in XML. And put in the database URL or NULL.

**My parcer:**

```
try {
            dbResult = new DBRss(RssActivity.this);
            ListMain listMain = (ListMain) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ListData");
            ListRss listRss = new ListRss();
            URL url = new URL(listMain.getUrl());
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser xmlPullParser = factory.newPullParser();
            xmlPullParser.setInput(getInputStream(url), null);
            boolean insideItem = false;
            int eventType = xmlPullParser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Parse ==>" + xmlPullParser.getName());
                    if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                        insideItem = true;
                    } else if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                        if (insideItem) {
                            listRss.setLink(xmlPullParser.nextText());
                        }
                    } else if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        if (insideItem) {
                            listRss.setTitle(xmlPullParser.nextText());
                        }
                    } else if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")) {
                        if (insideItem) {
                            SimpleDateFormat fromFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);
                            SimpleDateFormat toFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm", Locale.US);
                            String input = xmlPullParser.nextText();
                            Date date = null;
                            try {
                                date = fromFormat.parse(input);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String format = toFormat.format(date);
                            listRss.setPubDate(format);
                        }
                    } else if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                        if (insideItem) {
                            listRss.setDescription(xmlPullParser.nextText());
                        }
                    } else if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("enclosure")) {
                        if (insideItem) {
                            listRss.setImage(xmlPullParser.getAttributeValue(xmlPullParser.getNamespace(), "url"));
                        }
                        else if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("content")) {
                            for (int i = 0; i<xmlPullParser.getAttributeCount(); i++){
                                if (xmlPullParser.getAttributeName(i).contains("url"))
                                    listRss.setImage(xmlPullParser.getAttributeValue(i));

                            }
                        }

                    }
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

                    ListRss item = new ListRss(RssItemId, listMain.getUrl(), listRss.getPubDate(), listRss.getTitle(), listRss.getDescription(),
                            listRss.getLink(), listRss.getImage());
                    feedModels.add(item);
                    dbResult.insert(item);
                    insideItem = false;
                }
                eventType = xmlPullParser.next();
            }

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            exception = e;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            exception = e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            exception = e;
        }

        return exception;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug in the code. Everything worked.

```
...
                    if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                        **listRss = new ListRss(RssItemId, null, null, null, null, null, null);**
                        insideItem = true;
                   ...

                    feedModels.add(listRss);
                    ListRss item = new ListRss(RssItemId, listMain.getUrl(), listRss.getPubDate(), listRss.getTitle(), listRss.getDescription(),
                            listRss.getLink(), listRss.getImage());
                    dbResult.insert(item);
                    insideItem = false;
```